# CSS background image is not showing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

CSS background image is not showing.
This is my html code:

```
<div  class="container-fluid p-c b-g">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-infom">

    </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
.b-g{
   background-image: url(../images/bg/trading.jpg);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you inspect with a browser inspector if the image is loaded? Probably tha path for image are wrong

Comment: 'http://localhost/crypto/images/bg/trading.jpg'  when i put this path in browser image i showing that means path for image is correct

Comment: What are the code for the other classes ? container-fluid, p-c, row, col-sm-12 text-infom?

Comment: but when you inspect the element yuo can see if image are loaded, if don't you see an error, check that way.

Comment: in p-c class there is padding: 40px; currently text inform is blank class and reaming are bootstrap classes

Comment: add height:200px to class b-g to check if is working

Comment: better to add height 200px to class text-infom. Without any content, the height of all your divs will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

add some height to div it'll show

```css
.b-g{
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1285511592/1470391779/1500x500);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container-fluid p-c b-g">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-infom">

    </div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your keeping file path is wrong, check file loading or not by inspect in browser.

```
<style type="text/css">
.b-g {
   background-image: url("http://tipsforbeauties.com/gallery_gen//5c5f13b27a80afa16ca4184aec9a26c1_324.7619047619x220.jpg");
   width: 100%;
}
</style>
<div class="b-g">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For fit image to background (element, body or whatelse):

```
.b-g {
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/bg/trading.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Or you can add `background-size` property (remove `width` property).

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

And last one you can use like this:

```
background-image: #000 url('../images/bg/trading.jpg') repeat center center;
```