# why am I not getting the background-image for my div element?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background-image set on my div element, but I can't see it. Why is this happening?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>interior</title>
  <style>
    .pen {
      background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFFyGF8AZJB_M1TRnINMlytntLg1o5vx11xA&usqp=CAU");
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pen">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you div is empty (height=0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [background-image property is not showing the image in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166953/background-image-property-is-not-showing-the-image-in-css). Also see [CSS background image is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051516/css-background-image-is-not-showing).

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is now (in the question), you need to define a `height` for the `pen` element. By default (without contents) height remains zero, therefore no background image will be shown.

```css
.pen {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFFyGF8AZJB_M1TRnINMlytntLg1o5vx11xA&usqp=CAU");
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="pen">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need in this case a height of the element and possibly even background-size:
Like this:

```
height: 300px; /*for example*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: But as we are adding image the div element direct it can't set the height?

Comment: You are changing the background of the div, you are not adding an image inside the div, if that makes sense.

Comment: For example, if you set the background to #000 without setting the height, nothing will be seen. Because you have not set the height, you won't see the background, the same goes with images.

Answer (score 0):

There is no height set for the image, try this:

```
.pen {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFFyGF8AZJB_M1TRnINMlytntLg1o5vx11xA&usqp=CAU");
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div should have some height you can use this in your code and also you can adjust your height according to you . background-size:cover will cover whole background with your image.

`.pen{ backgroundimage:url("https://encryptedtbn0.gstatic.com/imagesq=tbn:ANd9GcTFFyGF8AZJB_M1TRnINMlytntLg1o5vx11xA&usqp=CAU"); width: 100vw; height: 50vh; background-size : cover;`